# How to provide the registration form inside a module or article?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'd like to make a custom landing page and on it I'd like to put the registration form. However since the registration form comes from a component I can't do that.

I've tried Plug-in include component extension, which is great except it doesn't work with SSL version of my site.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: you could always create a menu item, set the type to the user registration form, then set that menu item as the default homepage

Comment: Sadly, your best bet is probably [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication/15380). There is a reason that someone made a copy of it into a module. As far as I'm aware, there is no easy method for this built in to joomla. I have not used the linked to extension, but I would guess that it would do the trick or you may be able to get good help from its developer.

Comment: @Lodder What do you mean set menu item as default homepage?

Comment: @DavidFritsch I've seen that, unfortunately it doesn't play nice with my payment processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate landing page but this would make life rather hard. Importing files, changing the .htaccess etc.

What I propose you do it create a menu item and set the type to **User - Registration**. Save it then set it as the default page. I took a screenshot to help you with that. Setting it to default means it will basically become the homepage.

[image: screenshot]

Hope this helps

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying but the reason I wanted to put the registration component in a module or article is because I wanted to add extra details to that page. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Fair enough. In which case you can do a template override. Here is a documentation showing you how to achieve this: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

It basically means you can override the registration component rather than editing core Joomla files and thus adding you own text etc.

Comment: I use the registration component in many places but in this one case I want to make a customized page with the registration form. From what I understand of template overrides is that I'll be changing the registration component everywhere?

Comment: not necessarily. you can use a exception so that it's only specific to that menu item. There have been a few questions on SO regarding making code menu item specific.

Comment: ah yes, great idea (actually I'm one of the guys that asked that question a while back!). Thanks again @Lodder for your help